# Disproving the statement : Any subset $A$ of a Compact Topological Space $(X,\tau)$ is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> Any subset $A$ of a Compact Topological Space $(X,\tau)$ is compact.

> *Proof.* $A \subset X$. Let, $U$ be a open cover of $A$.
> Take any open cover $V$ of $X-A$. Then $W = (U \cup V)$ is a open cover of $X$. $X$ being compact there is a finite sub cover, say $F$ of $W$ that covers $X$. Then $F \cap U$ is a finite subcover of $A$. Therefore $A$ is compact.

I was thinking about the truthfulness of the statement I have given above and it turned out to be false because I got an example but when I'm proving it in this way, I can't find any mistakes whereas I know that there must be some mistake.

Can someone help me out with this? Thanks.

**Edit :** discussing with someone from my class we figured two points.
(1) Is it necessary that $F \cap U$ will cover F?
(2) Is it necessary that $F \cap U$ is must non-empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F\cap U$ might not be a cover of $A$ anymore. For example, take $X=[0,1]$ and $A=(0,1)$ with the standard topology. Let:

$U=\{(\frac{1}{n}, 1): n\in\mathbb{N}\}, \ \ \ \ V=\{[0,1]\}$

$U$ is an open cover of $A$ while $V$ is an open cover of $X$, and in particular of $X\setminus A$. Note that $V$ is already finite, so we can take the subcover $F=V$. But $F\cap U=\emptyset$ doesn't cover $A$.

Comment: Okay that's understandable. This is enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

We could take $\mathcal{V}=\{X\}$ as the cover for $X - A$, e.g. Then the finite subcover for $X$ must contain this element $X$, but you're in no way guaranteed that the finite subcover even contains elements that have anything to do with $A$ or $\mathcal{U}$ any more.

Answer (score 0):

The problem definitely lies in the claim that $F \cap U$ is a finite subcover of $A$. This is not necessarily an open cover of $A$ as the open cover of $A$ shouldn't necessarily contain any of the open sets of the open cover of $X$. You probably want the pairwise intersection of the open sets in the open covers which isn't necessarily finite!

Comment: I understand about the finite part. But tell me one thing, why $F \cap U$ is not a open cover of $A$? I took $U$ to be a collection of open sets in $X$ such that it covers $A$. So shouldn't $F \cap U$ be a open cover?

Comment: We can ignore the cardinality and consider $A = [0, 3], B = (1, 2)$.  $A$ is compact and an open cover can be $\{ [0, 2), (1, 3] \}$ whereas an open cover of $B$ can be $\{(1, 2)\}$. Note that the intersection is the empty set! What $\textit{is}$ an open cover of $B$ is the set of pairwise intersections $\{ [0, 2) \cap (1, 2), (1, 3] \cap (1, 2) \} = \{ (1, 2), (1, 2) \}$.

Comment: What topology are you considering in this case? And in this case is $A=[1,3]$ the main set $X$ ? If it's a usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ then how is $[0,2)$ is open set here? I'm having difficulty to see that.

Comment: Actually I meant if $F\cap U$ is non-empty. Then it must be an open cover of $A$. Is this tenable now?

Comment: Hey @Pritam! Here $A$ is the main set which has the inherited Euclidean topology from $\mathbb{R}$. I'm using different notation from your problem but yes, $A, B$ are $X, A$ from your example, respectively. As for your second comment, $F \cap U$ can still be infinite when not empty. The point I'm trying to make is that there is no direct relationship between the open covers of $A$ and $X$ that allows you to form a new open cover of $A$ by taking a simple intersection. Take this as an example: I can wear a shirt and pants to cover my entire body, but to cover my privates I only need underwear.

Comment: Obviously privates are a subset of the body but the cover $\{ \text{shirt}, \text{pants} \} \cap \{ \text{underwear} \} = \emptyset$. However, what does work as a cover is the intersection of the areas that these articles of clothing cover, which corresponds to the set of $\textit{pairwise intersections}$. I hope that sort of makes sense.

Comment: @green_frog thanks for your time. It makes sense. But can you tell me if $(\mathbb{R}, \tau)$ is the usual Topology then $\tau$ is the collection of all open interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Now for any subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ the subspace topology $\tau_A$ is defined by $\tau_A = \{A \cap V : V \in \tau \}$. So can you tell me how your cover $\{ [0, 2), (1, 3] \}$ is an open cover? I mean how these two sets are open in the subspace topology $(A, \tau_A)$?

Comment: Right so the topology on $\mathbb{R}, \tau$ is generated by the open intervals. If $A = [0, 3]$ then $[0, 2)$ in A is open as $[0, 2) = (-1, 2) \cap [0, 3]$. We can see similarly that $(1, 3] = (1, 4) \cap [0, 3]$ is open. The union $[0, 2) \cup (1, 3] = [0, 3]$ so the two form an open interval.

Comment: Thanks Again. I should've been able to see it myself.

Answer (score -1):

the family $\{F\cap U\}$ is not necessarily finite since  the family $\{U\}$ is not necessarily finite

Comment: But the family $F$ is finite so why the family $F \cap U$ won't be?

Comment: No of course. $F\cap U$ means that you intersect each element of $F$ with each element of $U$. So for example if $F= \{ (-\infty,0), (0, \infty)\}$ and $U=\{ (a,b): a< b \text{ real positive numbers}\}$, you can see that $F\cap U= U$.

Comment: @alphaomega This is not what is usually meant by $F\cap U$. According to the definitions of set theory, the elements of $F\cap U$ are the sets which belong to both $F$ and $U$. In your example, there are no such sets.

Comment: @Mark oh ok. My bad then. I thought it was pairwise intersection.